# axis-angle vs. quaternions pros and cons

Tags: 3d, quaternions, graphic

What are the pros and cons of using axis-angle versus quaternions in 3D rotations. Which method is faster? Which one takes up more resources?

Comment: Why don't you do a few quick Google searches on the two techniques and find out for yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Axis-angle don't support transformation composition. You will have to convert to matrix or quaternion form for multiplication, and convert back to Axis-angle.